# Passing array data to Morris Chart using JSON

Tags: php, jquery, morris.js

I want to pass dynamic array data to Morris Charts from my Ajax Success return.

I arrive to get all data for the line chart.

[image]

How to do with this code to send data.json and data.y in the  this.createAreaChartDotted parameters?

```
!function($) {
"use strict";

    var MorrisCharts = function() {};

    //creates area chart with dotted
    MorrisCharts.prototype.createAreaChartDotted = function(element, pointSize, lineWidth, data, xkey, ykeys, labels, Pfillcolor, Pstockcolor, lineColors) {
        Morris.Area({
            element: element,
            pointSize: 3,
            lineWidth: 1,
            data: data,
            xkey: xkey,
            ykeys: ykeys,
            labels: labels,
            hideHover: 'auto',
            pointFillColors: Pfillcolor,
            pointStrokeColors: Pstockcolor,
            resize: true,
            gridLineColor: '#eef0f2',
            lineColors: lineColors
        });
    },

    MorrisCharts.prototype.init = function() {
        var id_transmetteur = $('#id_transmetteur').val();
        var table_name = $('#table_name').val();
        var category_table = $('#category_table').val();

        $.ajax({
          method:"post",        
          dataType: 'json',
          url: $('#ajax').val()+'getDataCapteurs.php',
          success: function(data){
            if(data.status == 'success'){
                console.log(data.json); //Replace $areaDotData
                console.log(data.y); //Replace ['a', 'b'] in this.createAreaChartDotted()
            } else if(data.status == 'error'){
              if(data.messages.length>0){     
                var i;
                for (i = 0; i < data.messages.length; ++i) {
                    if(data.messages[i][0] == 'error'){
                        console.log('error');
                    }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        });

        //creating area chart with dotted
        var $areaDotData = [
                    { y: '2009', a: 10, b: 20 },
                    { y: '2010', a: 75,  b: 65 },
                    { y: '2011', a: 50,  b: 40 },
                    { y: '2012', a: 75,  b: 65 },
                    { y: '2013', a: 50,  b: 40 },
                    { y: '2014', a: 75,  b: 65 },
                    { y: '2015', a: 90, b: 60 }
                ];
        this.createAreaChartDotted('morris-area-with-dotted', 0, 0, $areaDotData, 'y', ['a', 'b'], ['Series A', 'Series B'],['#ffffff'],['#999999'], ['#52bb56', '#ebeff2']);

    },
    //init
    $.MorrisCharts = new MorrisCharts, $.MorrisCharts.Constructor = MorrisCharts
}(window.jQuery),

//initializing 
function($) {
    "use strict";
    $.MorrisCharts.init();
}(window.jQuery);
```

I tried to declare a variable after 
MorrisCharts.prototype.init = function(){
var data_chart; ...} and in ajax success : data_chart = data.json but when I tested my variable, she is undefined.

Thanks for helps.

Comment: I think you need to call the MorrisCharts function within the Ajax call. Something like success: function(data){ MorrisCharts }

Comment: Just with this? When I try after to put after the and of Ajax a console.log(dataJson), I receive a error like dataJson isn't a variable...

Comment: Can you console.log the variable from within the success callback?

Comment: You can see the result in the first picture

Comment: Ah yes. So I think your issue is a scoping issue. You're not going to be able to access variables in the success callback from outside the success callback. Two suggestions... You can fire the function you need from within the success callback... what I was eluding to in the comment above. Or, you could store the variables to the DOM and call them from there when you need them.

Comment: So I have to put in my Callback Ajax success -> this.createAreaChartDotted('morris-area-with-dotted', 0, 0, $dataJson, 'y', yData, ['Series A', 'Series B'],['#ffffff'],['#999999'], ['#52bb56', '#ebeff2']); ? I ever tried, and didn't work...

Comment: What's the error? createAreaChartDotted function probably doesn't have access to $areaDotData now.

Comment: Can I call the MorrisCharts function and pass variables in var MorrisCharts = function() {}; ?

Comment: I'll post an answer. I just won't be able to test because I don't have the rest of the code. Give me a few minutes.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to access that data from outside the success callback in your ajax call. So instead, do whatever you need to do within the success callback. Try initializing the Morris chart from within the ajax call.

```
!function($) {
"use strict";

var MorrisCharts = function() {};

//creates area chart with dotted
MorrisCharts.prototype.createAreaChartDotted = function(element, pointSize, lineWidth, data, xkey, ykeys, labels, Pfillcolor, Pstockcolor, lineColors) {
    Morris.Area({
        element: element,
        pointSize: 3,
        lineWidth: 1,
        data: data,
        xkey: xkey,
        ykeys: ykeys,
        labels: labels,
        hideHover: 'auto',
        pointFillColors: Pfillcolor,
        pointStrokeColors: Pstockcolor,
        resize: true,
        gridLineColor: '#eef0f2',
        lineColors: lineColors
    });
},

MorrisCharts.prototype.init = function(data, yData) {
    this.createAreaChartDotted('morris-area-with-dotted', 0, 0, data, 'y', yData, ['Series A', 'Series B'],['#ffffff'],['#999999'], ['#52bb56', '#ebeff2']);
},
//init
$.MorrisCharts = new MorrisCharts, $.MorrisCharts.Constructor = 
MorrisCharts
}(window.jQuery),

function($) {
"use strict";

var id_transmetteur = $('#id_transmetteur').val();
var table_name = $('#table_name').val();
var category_table = $('#category_table').val();

$.ajax({
    method:"post",        
    dataType: 'json',
    url: $('#ajax').val()+'getDataCapteurs.php',
    success: function(data){
    if(data.status == 'success'){
        var data = data.json;
        var yData = data.y;

        //Send data & Yaxis
        $.MorrisCharts.init(data, yData);

    } else if(data.status == 'error'){
        if(data.messages.length>0){     
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < data.messages.length; ++i) {
            if(data.messages[i][0] == 'error'){
                console.log('error');
            }
        }
        }
    }
    }
});
}(window.jQuery);
```

Comment: Yes I updated the answer with your edits. Is it working?

Comment: I get this error... morris.min.js:6 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of undefined
    at Object.b.parseDate (morris.min.js:6)
    at d.<anonymous> (morris.min.js:6)
    at d.setData (morris.min.js:6)
    at d [as constructor] (morris.min.js:6)
    at d [as constructor] (morris.min.js:6)
    at new d (morris.min.js:6)
    at Object.d [as Area] (morris.min.js:6)
    at MorrisCharts.createAreaChartDotted (capteurs.js:8)
    at MorrisCharts.init (capteurs.js:26)
    at Object.success (capteurs.js:53)

Comment: My data result seems to -> json :
"[{"timestamp": "18/06/2018 15:51:17","intensity" : 100},{"timestamp": "18/06/2018 15:51:17","intensity" : 100},{"timestamp": "21/06/2018 15:22:40","intensity" : 100},{"timestamp": "21/06/2018 15:22:40","intensity" : 100},{"timestamp": "21/06/2018 15:22:40","intensity" : 100}]"
status : "success"

Comment: Ok for no reasons... I found that... https://gerswin.com/angular-morris-chart-cannot-read-property-match-of-undefined-at-object-morris-parsedate-fd603369584e

Comment: Sorry V. Martin. I don't know what you mean in the above comment.